# How to add a column to a DataFrame that contains the name of the group to which a column value corresponds in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame "parameters" with one colum called "lcost" that varies from 0 - 0.1 and a numpy array "batch_lists" every 0.02 steps that covers all the possible lcost values like such:

```
parameters
 id        x           w         lcost
0102   0.580550    0.480814    0.013589
0103  -1.961033    0.546013    0.013204
0104   2.063441   -0.627297    0.035373
0105   0.319570    0.058588    0.035006
0106   1.318068   -0.802209    0.083996

batch_list=np.arange(0, 0.102, 0.002)
```

So, I want to add a column to parameters called "batch" to with the string name of the batch that the lcost value falls into. For example like this

```
parameters
 id        x           w         lcost          batch
0102   0.580550    0.480814    0.013589    (0.012-0.014]
0103  -1.961033    0.546013    0.013204    (0.012-0.014]
0104   2.063441   -0.627297    0.035373    (0.034-0.036]
0105   0.319570    0.058588    0.035006    (0.034-0.036]
0106   1.318068   -0.802209    0.083996    (0.082-0.084]
```

I do not know how to approach this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you require some good ol' [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) action.
See below:

```
import pd

print(parameters)

 id        x           w         lcost
0102   0.580550    0.480814    0.013589
0103  -1.961033    0.546013    0.013204
0104   2.063441   -0.627297    0.035373
0105   0.319570    0.058588    0.035006
0106   1.318068   -0.802209    0.083996
```

```
batch_list = np.arange(0, 0.102, 0.002)

parameters['batch'] = pd.cut(parameters.lcost, bins = batch_list)

print(parameters)

    id         x         w     lcost           batch
0  102  0.580550  0.480814  0.013589  (0.012, 0.014]
1  103 -1.961033  0.546013  0.013204  (0.012, 0.014]
2  104  2.063441 -0.627297  0.035373  (0.034, 0.036]
3  105  0.319570  0.058588  0.035006  (0.034, 0.036]
4  106  1.318068 -0.802209  0.083996  (0.082, 0.084]
```

Comment: Thanks. It was just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @EdgarUbaldoPeña, If I've answered your question it is standard procedure to mark it as answered